# Rsync backup - detect new directory and backup only from that directory

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

New cpanel daily backup is creating separate directories for daily backup. This creates problem when I try to user rsync to do an offsite backup since I would like to rsync only latest data. E.g.  On backup server I have directory "backup" and on server, from which we are pulling backups I get directories 2013-11-07, 2013-11-08 etc in backup directory. If I backup /backup directory on the server it will use allot more space so I would like to backup only latest directory in backup directory, eg 2013-11-08.

Is there a way to detect latest directory in backup directory and pass that directory name to rsync for backup ?

Answer (score 1):

> dirname=$(ls /backup |sort|tail -1); rsync -avP /backup/$dirname $backup_server:/backup/

Comment: or $(ls -atr |sort|tail -1)

Comment: hmmm... the problem is that ls  is taking modification time  and not creation time of files. So one time it could work correctly but if on of the directories was accessed/modified then it doesn't give correct result.  I tried with ls -ltu and it seems it gives ok result in that way. But, anyone knows any other command that would really take creation time of directory ?

Comment: Ok, I managed to make som progress.  The command would be dirname=$(ls -lt --time=ctime | sed -n 3p | sed 's/^.* //'  );

Comment: But when I combine that with rsync I get dirname=$(ls -lt --time=ctime | sed -n 3p | sed 's/^.* //'  ); rsync -ave /nib/$dirname/ -e 'ssh -pxxx' root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/disk/backup/test/
I get rsync: change_dir "/disk/backup/test" failed: No such file or directory (2)
Can anyone see what I'm missing here ?